# Bootstrap : add / remove fixed position to navbar on scroll

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

i am trying to stick navbar to top by adding position fixed  top to 0 on scroll for navbar-default , and place navbar back to same position while scrolling up (top 300),

below is my code

```
var height = jQuery('.navbar-default').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {


var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll>height) {
        $('.navbar-default').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px',left:'0px',right:'0px','z-index':'9999999999999999'});
        } else if(scroll<height){ 
// below i want to right code to position navbar to its original position   
      $('.navbar-default').css({position: 'relative', top: height,left:'0px',right:'0px','z-index':'9999999999999999'});
        }   

});
```

i am not sure if , else if part code is written right since navbar disappers if i scroll up, Please advise how can i fix this .Thanks

Edit : i tried to add navbar-fixed-top on scroll and then remove it but due to some reason it adds flickering effect to whole page so i am using positioning instead

Answer (score 1):

if by "flickering" you mean that elements below navbar jump up to fill the gap, the solution is to place your navbar inside a fixed height (height of your navbar) element like `<div>`. the reason it's happening is because when you fix navbar it's removed from the flow of the page and other elements move up to fill the gap. that's why a fixed height parent is required. this way you can use `.navbar-fixed-top`.
the problem I can see in your code is that when you set position back to relative, you set the top to height. relative positioned elements are positioned relative to their position on the page not the document or viewport, so you need to set it to 0.
also you don't need to put that `if` after `else`.